# How to configure a timeout for an SQL query in Groovy?

Tags: sql, groovy, timeout

How do I create a timeout for this operation: ?

```
def db = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://${mysql_host}:3306/${dbName}", 
    user, pass, 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
db.eachRow(query) { row ->
  // do something with the row
}
```

Comment: Similar question can be found [here](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/SQL-set-timeout-for-query-td372263.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the correct way would be something like this:

```
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "user", 
                  "pwd", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") 

sql.withStatement { 
   stmt -> stmt.queryTimeout = 10 
} 

sql.eachRow("select * from someTable", { 
 println it 
} )
```

of course, this is where I'd used Oracle, but I hope this can give you an idea.

Comment: If this answer helped, please don't forget to "accept as answer". It helps newbies(like me!) and the community as a whole :-)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reference you can cite?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might not be a general answer, but rather a database/driver-specific answer via parameters to the connection URL.

E.g. [for mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), I think that adding `connectTimeout=something&socketTimeout=something` might do the trick.