# How to handle PostgreSQL timeout in groovy

Tags: postgresql, groovy

In my Groovy script, I have following structure:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(connString, "user", "password", 
"org.postgresql.Driver")

sql.withTransaction {
     sql.withBatch(){}

     sql.withBatch(){}

     sql.withBatch(){}

     .........

}

sql.close()
```

I want to take care of timeout issues here.

But Sql API doesn't have any method for it.

So how can I do it? I am using PostgreSQL driver.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240975/how-to-set-connection-timeout-in-groovy-sql). But I get error:

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.setNetworkTimeout(Executor, int) is not yet implemented.

PS:

```
int[] modifyCount = sql.withBatch(batchSize, updateQuery) { ps ->
        keyValue.each { k,v ->
            ps.addBatch(keyvalue:k, newvalue:v)
        }
    }
```

In above code, when I try to add ps.setQueryTimeout(), error message says no such method defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Low-level timeouts** could be defined through connection properties:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

- **loginTimeout** Specify how long to wait for establishment of a database connection.
- **connectTimeout** The timeout value used for socket connect operations.
- **socketTimeout** The timeout value used for socket read operations.

These properties may be specified in either the connection URL or an additional Properties object parameter.

**Query timeout**. After connecting to the database you could define closure to be executed for each statement:

```
sql.withStatement{java.sql.Statement stmt->
    stmt.setQueryTimeout( MY_SQL_TIMEOUT )
}
```

Comment: inside withBatch you have [wrapper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper.html) and it does not have full access to a statement functions. try exactly `sql.withStatement` just after connection established and before any other sql operations.

Comment: you could try `sql.withBatch{ps-> ps.delegate.setQueryTimeout(...)  }` but this will use access to a private member `delegate`, and it's possible that will not work in  future versions.

Comment: second approach gives java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.

Comment: So, postgre driver does not support this. ((